# Usage of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext in a contorller

Tags: classpath, autowired

I'm running the example from the link below :

http://chathurangat.blogspot.se/2011/12/send-email-in-spring-with-gmail.html

And it works fine. My question is why

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("emailConfiguration.xml");
EmailSender emailSender=(EmailSender)context.getBean("emailSenderBean");
```

is placed in a controller?
Is there any better way of reading the xml file? and create the bean?

Can ClassPathXmlApplicationContext be autowired?

How can I use this example with JPA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Just use

Then you don't need the usage of declaration of the bean in the controller.

Thanks